# Insert inner a deep document in MongoDB with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to insert a city into a states array inner a country array, it is a bit confusing for me. I'm using MEAN. This is the MongoDB model:

```
var countrySchema = {
    countryName: { type: String, required: true },
    loc: [{ type: Number, required: true }],
    states: [{
        stateName: { type: String, required: true },
        loc: [{ type: Number, required: true }],
        cities: [{
            cityName: { type: String, required: true },
            loc: [{type: Number, required: true}]
        }]
    }]
};
```

When I insert a new City, I need update `cities` inner `states` and push another one.

I'm using POST metod, and this looks like this:

> ```
> api.post('/city/', wagner.invoke(function (Location) {
>     return function (req, res) {
>         return require('./Controllers/locationController').newCity(req, res, Location);
>     };
> }));
> ```

And is this `newCity` function:

> ```
> module.exports.newCity = function (req, res, Location) {
>     try {
>         var locations = req.body.locations;
>     } catch (error) {
>         return res.status(status.BAD_REQUEST).json({error: error.toString()});
>     }
>     Location.update({"countryName": locations.countryName, "states.stateName": locations.states.stateName}, {'$push': {'cities': locations.states.cities}}, function (error, city) {
>         if (error) {
>             return res.status(status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({error: error.toString()});
>         }
>         if (!city) {
>             return res.status(status.NOT_FOUND).json({error: error.toString()});
>         }
>         res.json({city: city})
>     });
> };
> ```

Most probably that the query on the update function is misconceived.

I'm sending the following JSON as a request:

> ```
> {
>     "locations": {
>         "countryName": "Mexico",
>         "loc": [1, 2],
>         "states": {
>             "stateName": "test one",
>             "loc": [1, 2],
>             "cities": {
>                 "cityName": "City for test one",
>                 "loc": [1, 2]
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

And I get this response:

```
{
    "city": {
        "ok": 0
        "n": 0
        "nModified": 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with `projection operator`, I didn't know it, but I researched.

The solution looks like that:

```
module.exports.newCity = function (req, res, Location) {
    try {
        var locations = req.body.locations;
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(status.BAD_REQUEST).json({error: error.toString()});
    }
    Location.update({
        "countryName": locations.countryName,
        'states.stateName': locations.states.stateName
    }, {
        '$push': {
            'states.$.cities': locations.states.cities
        }
    }, function (error, city) {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({error: error.toString()});
        }
        if (!city) {
            return res.status(status.NOT_FOUND).json({error: error.toString()});
        }
        res.json({city: city});
    });
};
```